# django 1.7 how to pass arguments to function regular expressions

Tags: regex, django, view

I am trying to pass an ID of a table to my function  but I am not sure what's going on.
if I hard code the ID number does work,  if I use the (?Pd+) with d+ so it use as many digits,  like in the tutorials. doesn't work.   should this be different?

thanks guys.

my urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    #url(r'^main_site/$', views.main_site),
    url(r'^vote/$', views.vote),
    url(r'^stadistics/$', views.stadistics),


    # using it like this doesn't work
    url(r'^vote/Restaurant_Info/(?P<rest_id>d+)/$', views.restaurant_menu),

    #testing the info of the restaurant
    # hard coding the id of the restaurant does work
    url(r'^vote/Restaurant_Info/4/$', views.restaurant_menu),
```

my view

```
    def restaurant_menu(request, rest_id="0"):
        response = HttpResponse()
        try:
            p = Restaurant.objects.get(id=rest_id)
            response.write("<html><body>")
            response.write("<p>name of the restaurant</p>")
            response.write(p.name)
            response.write("</body></html>")

        except Restaurant.DoesNotExist:
            response.write("restaurant not found")
        return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a backslash in your expression, currently `d+` matches the character `d` literally "one or more" times. The backslash in combination with a literal character creates a regular expression token with special meaning.

Therefore, `\d+` will match digits `0` to `9` "one or more" times.

```
url(r'^vote/Restaurant_Info/(?P<rest_id>\d+)/$', views.restaurant_menu)
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I tought was django,  but I should be looking into RE, does it work the same way for strings?  like      url(r'^/vote/thanks/(?P<your_email>\w+)/$', views.thanks),

Comment: Yes it does. Here is a good reference [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash. It should be `(?P<rest_id>\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r"^vote/Restaurant_Info/(?P<rest_id>\d+)/$", views.restaurant_menu),
```